# How to install wps office via flatpak in ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: 19.04, flatpak, wps-office

Flatpak has latest software than snaps. I tried installing wps office via flatpak but failed.

```
router@router:~$ flatpak install flathub com.wps.Office

Note that the directories 

'/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share'
'/home/router/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share'

are not in the search path set by the XDG_DATA_DIRS environment variable, so
applications installed by Flatpak may not appear on your desktop until the
session is restarted.

Looking for matches…
error: No remote refs found similar to ‘flathub’
router@router:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not follow [setup guide](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.wps.Office) for FlatPak.

You need to add flathub "repository" first with:

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

and then install WPS or any other FlatPak from *flathub*.

Comment: For people using `flatpak install --user ...` to install user-wide, might need to `flatpak remote-add --user ...`